# Git log ambiguous argument only in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have two branches, master and turtles, with turtles being ahead of master by one commit: 'I like turtles'.
In GitLab I have the following `.yml` file, which runs whenever a Merge Request is created, or updated by pushing the branch to merge:

```
update-doc:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
        - 'echo $(git log --abbrev-commit remotes/origin/master)'
        - 'echo $(git log --abbrev-commit remotes/origin/master..remotes/origin/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME})'
        - 'echo $(git cherry -v remotes/origin/master remotes/origin/turtles --abbrev=1)'
    only:
        - merge_requests
```

Running `git log --abbrev-commit remotes/origin/master..remotes/origin/turtles` or `git cherry -v remotes/origin/master remotes/origin/turtles` in Git Bash on my Windows machine and on the Linux VM where we are hosting GitLab returns the commit message 'I like turtles', as expected. But when the `.yml` file runs it cannot find the branch `remotes/origin/turtles` and I get the following output:

> $ echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
>   turtles
>   $ echo $(git log --abbrev-commit remotes/origin/master)
>   8406e4d Update .gitlab-ci.yml
>   $ echo $(git log --abbrev-commit remotes/origin/master..remotes/origin/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME})
>   fatal: ambiguous argument 'remotes/origin/master..remotes/origin/turtles': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
>   Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   'git  [...] -- [...]'
>   $ echo $(git cherry -v remotes/origin/master remotes/origin/turtles --abbrev=1)
>   fatal: Unknown commit remotes/origin/turtles

So GitLab clearly knows that there is the turtles branch as it's in the `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` variable, but can't seem to resolve the remotes/origin/turtles. I've tried without the remotes/origin/ part too but still no luck.

How can I get the GitLab runner to recognise that remote path of the merge request branch? Or is there another git command I could try that shows just the commits on the turtles branch?

Comment: I suspect Gitlab CI fetched only single branch `master`. Try to fetch the branch `turtles`: `git fetch origin $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME:$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME`

Comment: @phd fetching `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` fixed the error but then gave me all the commits on the branch (including those on `master`), but fetching `master` too fixed that issue. What is the meaning of the `:` between the branches in your comment? Not seen that notation before

Comment: See the docs https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt-ltrefspecgt. With `git fetch/pull`left to `:` is the remote ref, right to is the local ref (you fetch remote refs and update local refs). In `git push` it's the other way around (you push local refs to remote refs).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why the GitLab job runner wouldn't be able to see the branches on the repo?

Comment: Becuase it uses [`git clone --depth`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt) which implies `--single-branch`.

Answer (score 7):

In GitLab CI/CD, the default strategy for checking out code is to fetch the current branch with a shallow merge, e.g. `git fetch --depth 50 origin $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`. This explains why you see only the one branch.

You can fix this:

- By setting "Git shallow clone" to 0 in the web UI, or
- by setting `GIT_DEPTH: 0` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` to disable shallow clones, or
- by pulling/fetching any other branches you need, e.g. `git fetch origin master`

Refer to [the docs on shallow cloning](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/large_repositories/).