# How do I merge branches using GitLab CI/CD?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, cicd

```yaml
job1:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo 'Hello'
        - git branch
        - git merge cicd
    tags:
        - cicd
```

I want to merge a branch when I run a job, but the following error occurs after executing the job command:

```
merge: cicd - not something we can merge
Did you mean this?
    origin/cicd
```

I also tried using `git checkout master` and got the following error:

```
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Comment: CI/CD usually don't do full clone — they clone enough to test one commit. If you need more commits and branches you have to fetch them yourself. Don't forget to push after merge.

Answer (score 2):

> ```yaml
> job1:
>     stage: build
>     script:
>         - echo 'Hello'
>         - git branch
>         - git merge cicd
>     tags:
>         - cicd
> ```
>
> I want to merge a branch when I run a job, but the following error occurs after executing the job command:
>
> ```
> merge: cicd - not something we can merge
> Did you mean this?
>   origin/cicd
> ```

Firstly, note that by default, [GitLab CI uses *shallow clones*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68267237/10095231) in order to
be faster and to use less resources, which means that it does not fetch all
remote references.  In which case, it will likely not fetch all the commits
necessary to do a proper merge and thus you will have to [disable shallow
cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65388428/10095231).

Secondly, by default git does not create any branch (other than **master**/the
default branch for normal clones) when cloning a repository.  The same error
will probably happen if you clone the repository from scratch to your machine
with `git clone URL`, for example.  Only references to the remote branches will
be fetched by default (such as **origin/cicd**).

So you can either merge the remote branch directly:

```sh
git merge origin/cicd
```

Or create a normal branch from the remote branch and then merge:

```sh
git branch cicd origin/cicd
git merge cicd
```

The only difference should be what will be written on the auto-generated merge
commit message:

---

For merging the remote branch directly:

> Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/cicd'

For merging the local branch:

> Merge branch 'cicd'

---

> I also tried using `git checkout master` and got the following error:
>
> ```
> error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
> ```

The same commands above should work for **master**.

Comment: What is that repo's default branch? It could be `main` or any other name. A name-independent command to find can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67284026/4341322 ;-)